# Get selected value from dropdown in Jquery Context Menu item select change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contextmenu

I am using JQuery Context Menu plugin to show custom context menu
[Link Here](http://addyosmani.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html)

I am using select to show some options to filter in menu items as follows

```
var filterList={0:'title1',1:'title2',2:'title3'};

menuItems = {
    "true": { name: "Sort Ascending", icon: "asc" },
    "false": { name: "Sort Descending", icon: "desc" },
    "sep1": "----------------",
    "Clear": { name: "Clear filter on"+columnName, icon: "clear", disabled: false },
    select: {
        name: "Filter " + columnName, type: 'select', options: filterList,
        events: {
            change: function () {
                **//I want selected option text value here but dont know how??**
            }
        }
    }
};
```

how can i get value there on change function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function (e) {e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value} or

$(e.target).find(":selected").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Next time, try to explain your question better.

I don't know a lot of jQuery Context Menu, but for what I know, you can do something like this:

```
    function (e) {e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value}
```

Comment here if this code doesn't work for you. I will try help.